# Recursive function not returning what I want

Tags: python, function, recursion

I have a exercise I have to make for a course and this one in particular isn't quite working for me. The problem is simple and I have a work around but I am not sure if I am allowed to have multiple functions or if I am meant to have only one. I would prefer this working with only one function.

I have to write a simple function that takes n number of layers as parameter and calculates how many litres of soup it is in total (It has to be a recursive function). The layers are literal layers of cans working like this: top layer has 1^2 cans, second has 2^2, third has 3^2 and so on.

This is the function that successfully calculates the number of cans in n layers:

```
def lager(n):
    if n<1:
        return 0
    else:
        return n**2+lager(n-1)
```

the function returns for example 5 with n=2 and so on.
One can contains 0.407150407905 litres of soup so I should just multiply the result from this function with that right? So I thought why can't I do it in the same function? I tried editing the last line to:

```
return (n**2+lager(n-1))*0.407150407905
```

but for some reason (that I don't understand) it doesn't work with numbers of layers greater than 1.

Because I did not get this to work, I simply left the above function as it was and made a new one that takes the return value and multiplies it with 0.407150407905 and prints the result. But as I said I am not sure if I am allowed to write to functions. Can someone tell me why my theory isn't working?

Comment: Because you apply the multiplier at *every level of the recursion*, so by the time the first can gets to the output, it has been multiplied by `0.407...**n`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In each row `n` you have `n**2` cans, each of volume `0.407150407905` litres. However, your current function applies the `volume` multiplier to both:

- the number of cans on the current level; and
- the **volume** (*not* number) of the cans on the previous level.

This means that the multiplier is being applied to some of the cans repeatedly, effectively reducing their volume on each level. I would suggest one of two choices here:

1. Split this into two functions, where one gives you the number of cans and the other the total volume; or
2. Move the multiplier so it only multiplies *the cans on the current level*.

Therefore either:

```
def cans(layers):
    if layers < 1:
        return 0
    return (layers ** 2) + cans(layers-1)

def lager(layers=5, volume=0.407150407905):
    return cans(layers) * volume
```

or:

```
def lager(layers=5, volume=0.407150407905):
    if layers < 1:
        return 0
    return (volume * (layers ** 2)) + lager(layers-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your approach does not work because the factor `0.407...` is used in wrong positions in the recursive calculation. The approach using two steps is clearer: first calculate the number of cans, then multiply the number of cans with the can capacity.